# How do inductive proposition work in Coq?

Tags: coq

I was going through IndProp in software foundations and Adam Chlipala's chapter 4 book and I was having difficulties understanding inductive propositions.

For the sake of a running example, lets use:

```
Inductive ev : nat -> Prop :=
| ev_0 : ev 0
| ev_SS : forall n : nat, ev n -> ev (S (S n)).
```

I think I do understand "normal" types using `Set` like:

```
Inductive nat : Set :=
  | O : nat
  | S : nat -> nat.
```

and things like `O` just return the single object of type `nat` and `S O` is taking an object of type `nat` and returning another **different** one of the same type `nat`. By different object I guess I mean they have different values.

What I am confused is on how exactly the constructors for inductive props differ from inductive types `Set`. For `Set` it seems they just behave as function, a function that take values and return more values of that type. But for Inductive Propositions I am having a hard time figuring out what they do.

For example take `ev_0` as a simple example. I assume that is the name for the propositional object (value) `ev 0`. Since it's by itself `ev 0` must be a `Prop` a proposition. But what exactly makes it true? If its a proposition it could be false I assume. I guess the induction is confusing me. `ev` is the "function that returns objects of some type (proposition)", so ev 0 is just a proposition, but we have not said what `ev 0` should mean (unlike in my definition of natural number the base case is clear what its doing). In python I would expect to see

`n == 0: return True`

or something for the base case. But in this case it seems circular pointing to itself and not to something like `True`. I know there is a foundational misconception I have but I don't know what exactly what I am not understanding.

Also whats confusing me is the naming. In the `nat` the name `O` was crucial for building/constructing objects. But in the inductive definition `ev_0` seems to be more like a label/pointer to the real value `ev 0`. So I'd assume `ev_SS == ev_0 -? ev 2` doesn't really make sense but I don't know why. How are the labels here acting differently from the labels in the inductive types using `set`?

For `ev_SS` thats even more confusing. Since I don't know what labels are doing of course thats confusing me but look how this is pointing:

```
forall n : nat, ev n -> ev (S (S n))
```

so given a natural number `n` I assume it returns the proposition `ev n -> ev (S (S n))` (I am assuming `forall n : nat` is not part of the proposition object and its just there to indicate when the constructer that returns propositions works). So `forall n : nat, ev n -> ev (S (S n))` isn't really a proposition but `ev n -> ev (S (S n))`.

Can someone help me clarify how inductive proposition type really work in Coq?

---

Note I don't truly understand the difference between `Set` vs `Type` but I believe that would be a whole other post by itself.

---

Some more comments:

I was playing around with this some more and did:

```
Check ev_SS
```

and to my surprise got:

```
ev_SS
     : forall n : nat, ev n -> ev (S (S n))
```

I think this is unexpected because I didn't expect that the type of `ev_SS` (unless I am misunderstanding what `Check` is suppose to do) would be the definition of the function itself. I thought that `ev_SS` was a constructor so in my mind I thought that would do a mapping in this case `nat -> Prop` so of course thats the type I expected.

Comment: cross post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Coq/comments/a6v1lw/how_do_inductive_proposition_work_in_coq/?

Comment: now that I think about it after reading the current answer it might be the arguments thing that is confusing me a lot: After I saw  `ev_SS 0 ev_0` and `ev_SS 2 (ev_SS 0 ev_0)` and the fact it reads like nonsense to my brain (though I am sure they mean something) I realized that explaining how arguments work might be really useful to me, I already made a question about it a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807507/why-does-coq-use-unnamed-parameters-in-inductive-types-of-propositions

Answer (score 9):

So, first, it is normal for you to be confused by this, but it might be simpler than what you think!

There are two distinct concepts you are confused about, so let's take them one at a time. First, you mention that `ev 0` is a proposition, and wonder what makes it true. You will learn at some point that propositions and types are the same things, and the distinction between `Prop` and `Set` and `Type` is not that those things are different inherently.

So, when you define the type (or proposition) `nat`, you are creating a new type, and describing what values exist within it. You declare that there is a value `O`, that is a `nat`. And you declare that there is a parameterized value `S`, that is a `nat`, when passed a `nat`.

In the same way, when you define the type (or proposition) `ev`, you are creating a new type (well, it's actually a family of types indexed by values of type `nat`), and describing what values exist within those `ev` types. You declare that there is a value `ev_0`, that is an `ev 0`. And you declare that there is a parameterized value `ev_SS`, that is an `ev (S (S n))`, when passed a `n : nat` and an `ev n`.

So **you** made the proposition be true by having ways of creating values within it. You can also define a false proposition by having no constructors, or having constructors that can never be called:

```
Inductive MyFalse1 := . (* no constructor! *)

Inductive MyFalse2 :=
| TryToConstructMe : False ->  MyFalse2
| ThisWontWorkEither : 0 = 1 -> MyFalse2
.
```

I have declared two now types (or proposition), but there's no way to witness them because they either have no constructors, or no way to ever call those constructors.

---

Now regarding the naming of things, `ev_0`, `ev_SS`, `O`, and `S` are all the same kind of entity: a constructor. I'm not sure why you think that `ev_0` is a pointer to a value `ev 0`.

There is no meaning to assign to `ev n` as a proposition, other than it's a proposition that may be true if there is a way to construct a value with type `ev n`, and may be false if there is no way to construct a value with type `ev n`.

However, note that `ev n` has been carefully crafted to be inhabited for exactly those `n`s that are even, and to be uninhabited for exactly those `n`s that are odd. It's in this sense that `ev` captures a proposition. If you receive a value of type `ev n`, it essentially asserts that `n` is an even number, because the type `ev n` only contains inhabitants for even values:

- `ev 0` contains 1 inhabitant (`ev_0`)
- `ev 1` contains 0 inhabitant
- `ev 2` contains 1 inhabitant (`ev_SS 0 ev_0`)
- `ev 3` contains 0 inhabitant
- `ev 4` contains 1 inhabitant (`ev_SS 2 (ev_SS 0 ev_0)`)
- etc.

---

Finally, for the difference between `Set`, `Prop`, and `Type`, these are all universes within which you can create inductive types, but they come with certain restrictions.

`Prop` enables an optimization for code generation. It's essentially a way for you, the programmer, to mark some type as being only used for verification purposes, never used for computation purposes. As a result, the type-checker will force you to never compute on proofs within the `Prop` universe, and the code generation will know that it can throw away those proofs as they don't participate in computational behavior.

`Set` is just a restriction of `Prop` to avoid dealing with universe levels. You don't really need to understand this until later in your learning process.

You should really try to not think of `Prop` as being a magical thing different than `Set`.

---

The following might help you: we could rewrite the definitions of `nat` and `ev`, in a completely equivalent way, as:

```
Inductive nat1 : Set :=
| O : nat1
| S : nat1 -> nat1
.
(* is the same as *)
Inductive nat1 : Set :=
| O : nat1
| S : forall (n : nat1), nat1
.

(* and *)
Inductive ev : nat -> Prop :=
| ev_0 : ev 0
| ev_SS : forall (n : nat), ev n -> ev (S (S n))
.
(* is the same as *)
Inductive ev : nat -> Prop :=
| ev_0 : ev 0
| ev_SS : forall (n : nat) (e : ev n), ev (S (S n))
.
```

Any time you see a type looking like `a -> b`, it's really a short-hand for `forall (_ : a), b`, that is, we expect an input of type `a`, and return an output of type `b`.

The reason why we write `forall (n : nat)` in `ev_SS` is that we **have** to give a name to the first argument, because the type of the second argument will depend on it (the second argument has type `ev n`).

Comment: you asked why I think `ev_0` or `ev_SS` are "pointers". The reason I am confused about that (still) is because for `S` the argument is explicit in the definition `(n : nat)` but that argument is unnamed (for some mysterious reason to me) for `ev_0` and `ev_SS` therefore it looks by looking at the "constructor" (which should be a function and function take arguments and this one doesn't have arguments, at least not ones I can see in the definition). So to a novice `ev_0` looks like it "corresponds" to `ev 0` and `ev_SS` looks like it's corresponding to a very hairy quantified implication.

Comment: but they certainly don't look like constructors which are functions and functions take arguments.

Comment: I think after reading your answer the crucial thing that is confusing me is how "arguments work in inductive proposition". The reason I saw this is because `ev_SS 0 ev_0` and `ev_SS 2 (ev_SS 0 ev_0)` read like nonsense to my brain (though I am sure they mean something). Perhaps clarifying the arguments thing could me a lot. I even made a question about it already a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807507/why-does-coq-use-unnamed-parameters-in-inductive-types-of-propositions can help me a lot.

Comment: I added a little extra bit about why the `nat ->` in the definition of `S` and the `forall (n : nat),` in the definition of `ev_SS` are really the same type of thing, where we declare an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

If you replace `Prop` with `Set` then you say you understand the definition:

```
Inductive ev' : nat -> Set :=
| ev_0' : ev' 0
| ev_SS' : forall n : nat, ev' n -> ev' (S (S n)).
```

For every `n : nat` we think of `ev' n` as a type which has some elements, or perhaps none. Because this is an inductive definition, we can tell what the elements of `ev' 0` are: the only element is `ev_0'` (or to be more precise, every closed term of type `ev' 0` computes to `ev_0;`). There are no elements of `ev_0 1`, but there is an element of `ev 2'`, namely `ev_SS' 0 ev_0'`. In fact, a little bit of thinking shows that `ev n` is either empty or a singleton, depending on whether `n` is even or odd.

It's exactly the same when we switch from `Set` to `Prop`, except that the reading is different: `Set` is a (large) type of types, `Prop` is also a type of types (they are *universes*). Each element of `Prop` is a type (but we prefer to call it a "proposition") which has some elements (but we prefer to call them "proofs"). So consider this:

```
Inductive ev : nat -> Prop :=
| ev_0 : ev 0
| ev_SS : forall n : nat, ev n -> ev (S (S n)).
```

For every `n : nat`, we think of `ev n` as the statement that `n` has the property `ev`, whatever that property might be. For any give `n`, there may be a proof of `ev n`, in which case `n` has the property `ev`, or there may be no such proof, in which case `n` does not have the property `ev`. Because this is an inductive definition, we can tell what the proofs of `ev_0` are: they all compute to `ev_0'`. There are no proofs of `ev_0 1`, but there is a proof of `ev 2`, namely `ev_SS 0 ev_0`. In fact, a little bit of thinking shows that `ev n` has a proof if, and only if, `n` is even. We now understand that `ev` is the property of being "even".

This is knows as "propositions as types".

We observed that `ev' 0` contains just one element `ev_0'`. The type `unit` also contains just one element `tt`. Does this mean that `ev' 0` and `unit` are equal? No, but they are *equivalent* because we can provide functions `ev' 0 -> unit` and `unit -> ev' 0` which are inverses of each other.

We can ask the same question about `ev 0`: is it equal to `True`? No, but they are *equivalent* because we can prove the implications `ev 0 -> True` and `True -> ev' 0`.

One starts to wonder what the difference between `Prop` and `Set` is. For a type `P : Prop` all of its elements are considered equal, i.e., Coq does not allow us to distinguish between them. (This is a bit of a pedagocical lie, because in reality Coq is *agnostic* about whether all the element of `P` are considered equal, but perhaps it's better not to get into this right now.)